# WKWebView и шэринг/сохранение файлов

Tags: swift

В `SFSafariViewViewController` при открытии URL с не поддерживаемым типом файла показывается вьюшка как на скриншоте с возможностью шэринга файла в другие приложения (`Open in...` кнопка), в том числе с опцией сохранения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно реализовать эту опцию именно со скачиванием файла? Пробовал через `UIActivityViewContoller` сделать, передавая туда URL, но в таком случае предлагается куда меньше опций и шарится именно ссылка на файл, а не сам файл. Я знаю, что можно просто скачать и расшарить его, но проблема в том, что могут быть большие файлы, а следовательно, пользователю придется ожидать все это время. Как можно реализовать задумку и возможно ли это вообще?